# How big is the chance that a arbitrary man is taller than a arbitrary woman?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I'm a first year mathematics student, and I'm having trouble with computing the following:

Assume that in a country the height $X$ of men is normally distributed, with $\mu_X = 180$ (the expected value), $\sigma_X = 6$ (the standard deviation) and the same for the height of women, $Y$, with $\mu_Y = 173$ and $\sigma_Y = 5$.

How big is the chance that a arbitrary man is taller than a arbitrary woman?

I don't know how to solve this question. I'm able to compute chances like $\mathbb{P}(X \geqslant k)$ or $\mathbb{P}(X \leqslant k)$ for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$ using the formula $\mathbb{P}(X \leqslant k) = \Phi(\frac{k + \frac{1}{2} - \mu}{\sigma})$. I think I have to compute in some way $\mathbb{P}(X > Y)$, but I don't see how to do that. Could you please help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know how to find the distribution of $X-Y$ when $X$ and $Y$ are normally distributed and independent? If so then note that $\mathbb P(X>Y)$ is the same as $\mathbb P(X-Y>0)$.

Comment: @Rahul So do I have to compute the expected value and standard deviation of $X - Y$ and then use the $\Phi$ formula I stated above?

Comment: That $\frac12$ in $\Phi(\frac{k + \frac{1}{2} - \mu}{\sigma})$ is only for discrete distributions, e.g. the binomial distribution. This distribution is continuous, so it's $\Phi(\frac{k - \mu}{\sigma})$.

Comment: @TonyK Thanks! I completely understand it now! I will accept your answer as the best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of normal distributions with means $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ and variances $\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_2^2$ is a normal distribution with mean $\mu_1+\mu_2$ and variance $\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2.$ So the difference in heights is normal with mean 7 and variance $61\approx7.81^2.$ Now just use the standard formula to see when this is positive.

Comment: Ok I tried that, but then I get $\mathbb{P}(X - Y > 0) = 1 - \Phi(\frac{\frac{1}{2} - 7}{\sqrt{61}}) = \Phi(\frac{13}{2 \sqrt{61}})$, and that is not correct

Comment: @Peter: See my comment to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The probability density function of a $N(\mu,\sigma)$ random variable $X$ is given by:
$$ f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$
hence our probability is given by the integral:

$$ \mathbb{P}[X\geq Y]=\frac{1}{60\pi}\iint_{x>y}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-180)^2}{72}-\frac{(y-173)^2}{50}\right)\,dx\,dy\approx\color{red}{81.49\%}.$$